# Swift TableView Population

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, model, storyboard

I have a tableview controller, that I am designing using Storyboard. The prototype cell is very basic, it just has two labels. A name label, and a date label.

When I run my program, the style is there (font, etc.), but it seems like the constraints aren't working? Also, the cell color doesn't show (only the tableview background shows), and the cell dividers are missing. The labels overlap each other, and when I set the cell height to 75, it doesn't appear that tall.

This is what my cell looks like compiled:
[See tableview here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WAlQD.png)

I made a model for the table view cell as shown here (IdeaCell is properly set on the prototype cell in storyboard):

```
class IdeaCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var ideaNameLbl: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var ideaDateLbl: UILabel!


    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
        if selected {
            self.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 1, alpha: 0.2).cgColor
        } else {
            self.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        }
    }

    func configureCell(idea : CoreIdea) {
        let name = idea.name
        ideaNameLbl.text = name

        let date = idea.date
        ideaDateLbl.text = date
    }
}
```

And my tableview view controller relevant code is here (reuse identifier (ideaCell) is properly set on the prototype cell in storyboard):

```
class IdeaVC: UITableViewController { 
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ideaCell", for: indexPath) as? IdeaCell {
            let idea = ideas[indexPath.row]
            cell.configureCell(idea: idea)
            return cell
        } else {
            return UITableViewCell()
        }
    }
}
```

UPDATE:
After adding the heightForRowAt function, my cells are the proper height, and constraints are working as they should be. For some reason the cell background color is missing, and the cell divider is not appearing (the font, and font color work). They were all set in the storyboard.

Here is a screenshot of my cells:
[missing cell style](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iIwM2.png)

UPDATE 2:
I set the divider and background like this:

```
self.tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
self.tableview.separatorColor = UIColor.white
```

Hope this helps someone! I honestly don't know why my values from storyboard didn't work, but setting them in the viewDidLoad worked great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you told your tableview the height of the tableviewcell? If not try this. Its one of your tableviews delegate methods.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 75.0 //Set your cell height that you want to appear in your tableview
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I will give that a try when I am home this evening. I was under the impression that I wouldn't need that method since I have the height set in the storyboard?

Comment: Try it and see if it works out, let me know what it does for you :P

Comment: Update: It works! Mostly! The cells are now properly constrained. It isn't showing the cell background color, or the line dividers between cells. I will dig through the docs as I assume there are other methods that will help with those. Thanks!

Comment: Can you post a new screenshot of your cells? I can try to help you with the rest.

Comment: I just updated my question with the most recent screen shot. Thanks so much!

Comment: I also got the background color to properly populate with the willDisplay cell function. Still working on the cell divider though.

Answer (score 0):

i think you must override the number of Item , and height for row at function. and set the constraint on UITableViewCell between name and date label.

Comment: I currently have these constraints: name = top 0, left 0, right 0 and date = bottom 0, left 0, right 0. I will add in the height for row at function, and see how that works out. I'll also add a constraint between name and date. What would altering the number of items do in this case? I have the number of items set to the number of items in my array (which is properly populating).